# How to encrypt strings using MD5?

Tags: tidesdk

This is my first time using TideSDK. I want to ask a simple question.

How do i encrypth a string using MD5 in tidesdk?

Comment: Note that MD5 is a hashing algorithm, not an encryption algorithm.

Comment: Found in the manual. Ti.Codec.digestToHex(Ti.Codec.MD5,password+pass_str)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dadait said already, `Ti.Codec` holds that functionality. If you want to hash in php/python/ruby, those have functions/modules for that to. In PHP you can just call the `md5` function, and in Python I believe the way to go would be `hashlib` module.